# How can the Chrome Settings page be opened through a hyperlink?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-os, chrome-options

I am building an app that requires the user to change a Chrome setting. It will be more convenient to send the user directly to `chrome://settings` instead of having them open it manually via the menu, but when I try and open it directly or through a hyperlink on a web page, it always goes to `about:blank#blocked`. I have tried this on Windows, MacOS, and ChromeOS (including through a link in a TextView in an Android app), but the result is the same. Is this possible, or is it completely blocked for security or some other purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'll save you the trouble and let you know its not possible, and yes you're right due to security reasons

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome on my local machine chrome://settings/ works. Well surely not impossible but still not that easy maybe this helps

```
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/11564174?hl=en
```

Comment: Are you able to open it through a hyperlink embedded in a web page?